How do I create a userscript that creates a button on a webpage, that when clicked, runs the GM_registerMenuCommand for that userscript?
I have a userscript that includes a GM_registerMenuCommand('Render LaTeX', () => { (and so forth) that makes part of the userscript only run when manually triggered by selecting the ViolentMonkey addon from my browser bar, then clicking the button labeled "Render LaTeX".
I want to add a button to the webpage this userscript is set to match, which when clicked does the above. I'm just at a loss for how to do so. The only information even regarding buttons I've yet been able to find was here.
I've tried tinkering with the code provided in the second answer to the linked question. I was able to adjust the text and positioning, but I couldn't figure out how to make the button do what I want or change its appearance to better fit into the website it's going on.
// ==UserScript==
// @name        TeX Button
// @namespace   all
// @match     https://mail.google.com/mail/*
// @version     1
// @grant       none
// ==/UserScript==

(function(){
    'use strict'

  window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    addButton('TeX', selectReadFn)
    })

    function addButton(text, onclick, cssObj) {
        cssObj = cssObj || {position: 'absolute', bottom: '92.375%', left:'19.35%', 'z-index': 3}
        let button = document.createElement('button'), btnStyle = button.style
        document.body.appendChild(button)
        button.innerHTML = text
        button.onclick = onclick
        Object.keys(cssObj).forEach(key => btnStyle[key] = cssObj[key])
        return button
    }

    function selectReadFn() {
        [...document.getElementsByClassName('MN')].filter(isRead).forEach(element => element.click())
    }

    function isRead(element) {
        childs = element.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.getElementsByClassName('G3')
        return ![...childs].some(e => e.innerText.search(/unread/i)!==-1)
    }

}())


Below is the code with the GM_registerMenuCommand I mentioned. I don't know if this is actually needed for reference, but I figured it couldn't hurt to share.
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LaTeX for Gmail v2.1
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://mail.google.com/mail/*
// @grant       GM_registerMenuCommand
// @grant       GM_addElement
// @require     https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.min.js
// @version     2.1
// @author      /u/MistralMireille & /u/LoganJFisher
// @description Adds support for TeXTheWorld delimiters to Gmail, and an register menu to activate rendering using traditional LaTeX delimiters
// ==/UserScript==

GM_addElement('link', {
  rel: "stylesheet",
  src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.css"
});

function renderLatex() {
  document.querySelectorAll("#\\:1 > .nH .aHU.hx > [role='list'] > [role='listitem'][aria-expanded='true']").forEach(message => {
let subportion = message.querySelector("[data-message-id]"); // need to select a subportion of [role='listitem'] to stop rendering latex in the textinput
if(subportion) {
  message = subportion;
}
message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\[;(.+?);\]/g, (match, p1) => {
  return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: false });
});
message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\[\(;(.+?);\)\]/g, (match, p1) => {
  return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: true });
});
  });
}

GM_registerMenuCommand('Render LaTeX', () => {
  document.querySelectorAll("#\\:1 > .nH .aHU.hx > [role='list'] > [role='listitem'][aria-expanded='true']").forEach(message => {
    let subportion = message.querySelector("[data-message-id]"); // need to select a subportion of [role='listitem'] to stop rendering latex in the textinput
    if(subportion) {
      message = subportion;
    }
    message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\\\[(.+?)\\\]/g, (match, p1) => {
      return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: true });
    });
    message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\$\$(.+?)\$\$/g, (match, p1) => {
      return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: true });
    });
    //message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\\begin\{displaymath}(.+?)\\end\{displaymath}/g, (match, p1) => {
      //return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: true });
    //});
    //message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\\begin\{equation}(.+?)\\end\{equation}/g, (match, p1) => {
      //return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: true });
    //});
    message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\\\((.+?)\\\)/g, (match, p1) => {
      return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: false });
    });
    message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\$(.+?)\$/g, (match, p1) => {
      return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: false });
    });
    message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\\begin\{math}(.+?)\\end\{math}/g, (match, p1) => {
      return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: false });
    });
  });
});

function waitForElement(queryString) {
  let count = 0;
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
let findInterval = setInterval(() => {
  let waitElement = document.querySelector(queryString);
  if(waitElement) {
    clearInterval(findInterval);
    resolve(waitElement);
  } else if(count > 20) {
    clearInterval(findInterval);
    reject(`Couldn't find waitElement: ${queryString}.`);
  } else {
    count += 1;
  }
}, 100);
  });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  waitForElement("#\\:1 > .nH").then(messagesDiv => {
(new MutationObserver((mutationRecords, observerElement) => {
  mutationRecords.forEach(mutationRecord => {
    switch(mutationRecord.type) {
      case "childList":
        mutationRecord.addedNodes.forEach(addedNode => {
          console.log(addedNode);
          if(addedNode.tagName === "DIV" && addedNode.getAttribute("role") === "listitem") {
            renderLatex();
          }
        });
        break;
      case "attributes":
        if(mutationRecord.target.tagName === "DIV" && mutationRecord.target.getAttribute("role") === "listitem" && mutationRecord.attributeName === "aria-expanded") {
          renderLatex();
        }
    }
  });
})).observe(messagesDiv, { childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true});
  });
});


Please show the code you tried.

Editing the question now with the code from the second answer from the above question, but with the button's label and position changed. There is nothing in it about changing its function, since I have no clue how to even approach that. Obviously this will have to be added into the code with the GM_registerMenuCommand, but I think that's just a matter of copy/pasting it in.

Also editing in the code with the GM_registerMenuCommand, just for good measure.

you want to run the same function from both the menuCommand and the injected button? simply add the same callback for both: GM_registerMenuCommand('Render LaTeX', renderLatex) and button.onclick = renderLatex.

@GTK I'm a big confused how to change GM_registerMenuCommand('Render LaTeX', () => {. Just placing renderLatex) in after the comma doesn't work.

@LoganJ.Fisher is it the exact same code as renderLatex() ?? if so just delete the arrow function () => { ... }  and replace it with renderLatex

@GTK I'm trying to implement this based on what you're saying, but it's just not working. I'm obviously missing something essential. Could you leave an answer copying the above code with this added in? Sorry.

you have posted 2 separate scripts, do you want to combine them? also in your first script the button calls selectReadFn which has nothing to do with renderLatex?

@GTK The first script is just an example of a button since the first comment asked me to share that. The second script is the one I'm actually working on. I want that second one to generate a button that triggers renderLatex.

Here's your script modified to add a button and a menuCommand that will both call renderLatex:
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LaTeX for Gmail v2.1
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://mail.google.com/mail/*
// @grant       GM_registerMenuCommand
// @grant       GM_addElement
// @require     https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.min.js
// @version     2.1
// @author      /u/MistralMireille & /u/LoganJFisher
// @description Adds support for TeXTheWorld delimiters to Gmail, and an register menu to activate rendering using traditional LaTeX delimiters
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

/* globals katex */

GM_addElement('link', {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.css"
});

function renderLatex() {
    console.log('rendering latex...');
    const messages = document.querySelectorAll("#\\:1 > .nH .aHU.hx > [role='list'] > [role='listitem'][aria-expanded='true']");
    messages.forEach(message => {
        let subportion = message.querySelector("[data-message-id]"); // need to select a subportion of [role='listitem'] to stop rendering latex in the textinput
        if(subportion) {
            message = subportion;
        }
        message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\[;(.+?);\]/g, (match, p1) => {
            return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: false });
        });
        message.innerHTML = message.innerHTML.replace(/\[\(;(.+?);\)\]/g, (match, p1) => {
            return katex.renderToString(p1, { throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: true });
        });
    });
}

function waitForElement(queryString) {
    let count = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let findInterval = setInterval(() => {
            let waitElement = document.querySelector(queryString);
            if(waitElement) {
                clearInterval(findInterval);
                resolve(waitElement);
            } else if(count > 20) {
                clearInterval(findInterval);
                reject(`Couldn't find waitElement: ${queryString}.`);
            } else {
                count += 1;
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    waitForElement("#\\:1 > .nH").then(messagesDiv => {
        addButton(messagesDiv);

        (new MutationObserver((mutationRecords, observerElement) => {
            mutationRecords.forEach(mutationRecord => {
                switch(mutationRecord.type) {
                    case "childList":
                        mutationRecord.addedNodes.forEach(addedNode => {
                            console.log(addedNode);
                            if(addedNode.tagName === "DIV" && addedNode.getAttribute("role") === "listitem") {
                                renderLatex();
                            }
                        });
                        break;
                    case "attributes":
                        if(mutationRecord.target.tagName === "DIV" && mutationRecord.target.getAttribute("role") === "listitem" && mutationRecord.attributeName === "aria-expanded") {
                            renderLatex();
                        }
                }
            });
        })).observe(messagesDiv, { childList: true, subtree: true, attributes: true, attributeOldValue: true});
    });
});

function addButton(parent) {
    GM_registerMenuCommand('Render LaTeX', renderLatex);
    GM_addElement(parent, 'button', {
        id: 'LatexButton',
        textContent: 'RENDER LATEX'
    });

    parent.querySelector('#LatexButton').addEventListener('click', renderLatex);
}

*You can easily add styles to this button using GM_addStyle(css).

EDIT:
Latest version of the script:
// ==UserScript==
// @name        LaTeX for Gmail v2.1
// @namespace   Violentmonkey Scripts
// @match       https://mail.google.com/mail/*
// @grant       GM_registerMenuCommand
// @grant       GM_addElement
// @require     https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.min.js
// @version     2.1
// @author      /u/MistralMireille & /u/LoganJFisher
// @description Adds support for TeXTheWorld delimiters to Gmail, and an register menu to activate rendering using traditional LaTeX delimiters
// @noframes
// ==/UserScript==

/* globals katex */

let LATEX_TOGGLE_STATE = true;

function renderLatex(html) {
    const katexReplaceList = [
        [/\[;(.+?);\]/g, false],
        [/\[\(;(.+?);\)\]/g, true],
        [/\\\[(.+?)\\\]/g, true],
        [/\$\$(.+?)\$\$/g, true],
        [/\\\((.+?)\\\)/g, false],
        [/\$(.+?)\$/g, false],
        [/\\begin\{math}(.+?)\\end\{math}/g, false]
    ];

    katexReplaceList.forEach( ([regex, display]) => {
        html = html.replace(regex, (m, p) => katex.renderToString(p, {throwOnError: false, output: "mathml", displayMode: display}));
    });

    return html;

}

function refreshLatex(){
    const messages = document.querySelectorAll("#\\:1 [role=list] > [role=listitem][aria-expanded=true]");
    messages.forEach(message => {
        let subportion = message.querySelector("[data-message-id] > div > div > div[id^=':'][jslog]");
        message = subportion || message;
        message.oldHTML = message.oldHTML || message.innerHTML;

        message.innerHTML = LATEX_TOGGLE_STATE ? renderLatex(message.innerHTML) : message.oldHTML;
    });
}

function toggleLatex() {
    LATEX_TOGGLE_STATE = !LATEX_TOGGLE_STATE;
    refreshLatex();
}

function waitForElement(queryString) {
    let count = 0;
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let findInterval = setInterval(() => {
            let waitElement = document.querySelector(queryString);
            if(waitElement) {
                clearInterval(findInterval);
                resolve(waitElement);
            } else if(count > 20) {
                clearInterval(findInterval);
                reject(`Couldn't find waitElement: ${queryString}.`);
            } else {
                count += 1;
            }
        }, 100);
    });
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    waitForElement("div#\\:3").then(messagesDiv => {
        GM_registerMenuCommand('Toggle LaTeX', toggleLatex);
        messagesDiv.addEventListener('click', refreshLatex);
        const target = document.querySelector('div#\\:4');
        const observer = new MutationObserver( () => { refreshLatex(); addButton() });
        observer.observe(target, {attributes: false, childList: true, subtree: false});
    });
});


function addButton() {
    const moveBtn = document.querySelector('div#\\:4 div[title="Move to"]');
    if (!moveBtn) return;

    GM_addElement(moveBtn.parentElement, 'div', {
        id: 'LatexButton',
        role: 'button',
        style: 'cursor: pointer; margin: 0 12px 0 12px;',
        'aria-label': 'Toggle LaTeX',
        'data-tooltip': 'Toggle LaTeX',
        textContent: 'LaTeX'
    });

    const latexButton = document.querySelector('#LatexButton');
    latexButton.addEventListener('click', toggleLatex);
}

if (window.trustedTypes && window.trustedTypes.createPolicy && !window.trustedTypes.defaultPolicy) {
    window.trustedTypes.createPolicy('default', {
        createHTML: string => string
    });
}

GM_addElement('link', {
    rel: "stylesheet",
    src: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.11/dist/katex.css"
});


This doesn't seem to be working. The automatic render for the [; and [(; delimiters is still working, but neither the button this makes nor the register menu's option are causing the TeX inside the other delimiters to render. I should note that the register menu's option was previously working.

To clarify, [; and [(; are meant to be automatic. \[ \( $ $$ and \begin{math} are all supposed to be manually triggered. I'd later like to work out how to make it possible to toggle between the rendered and unrendered states, but that's a later problem.

Oh, I got it to work! I'm marking your answer as accepted, but I'm also going to provide my own answer with the edited code. Thank you!

@LoganJ.Fisher glad it helped! the render function modifies the html, are you not getting a This document requires 'TrustedHTML' assignment error in the console?

I'm not sure. Where would I look for that, and what would the significance of that be?

@LoganJ.Fisher it means  message.innerHTM = ... is not working, I got this error when I ran your script, If you could provide a sample email that contains latex that would help testing.

Just email yourself the following on different lines in the email: [;a^{2};] [(;a^{2};)] \(a^{2}\) \[a^{2}\] $a^{2}$ $$a^{2}$$ \begin{math}a^{2}\end{math} - the first two should render automatically, and the remaining 5 will render upon clicking the button. If you want, you can also reply to yourself in an email chain - it works (although if an email isn't expanded when you click the button, it won't render until you expand it and click the button again). These order I wrote these will alternate between inline and display renderings.

@LoganJ.Fisher I added a fix for the error in the edit, I am using Chrome + tampermonkey, and it did not work without it.

Just throw that additional bit on at the end? I'm using Firefox + ViolentMonkey and had no issue, but I certainly want this to be as widely compatible as possible for when I share it with my colleagues to use.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
